# SecurityException: Permission Denial even when I am taking runtime permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions, crashlytics-android, android-securityexception

I am getting below exception on Crashlytics from multiple devices with Android 7.0-

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/video/media from pid=7070, uid=12033 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:532)
       at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
       at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I have researched and found out that this exception occurs when we don't take runtime exception in Android 6.0+ devices.
But in my project i have used runtime permission wherever required.The crash doesn't specify any particular line of my project.
Below code I am using to take runtime permission from user-

```
  uploadVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                        getPermission();
                    else
                        uploadVideo();

                }
            });


private void getPermission() {
        String[] params = null;
        String writeExternalStorage = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        String readExternalStorage = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

        int hasWriteExternalStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, writeExternalStorage);
        int hasReadExternalStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readExternalStorage);
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (hasWriteExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissions.add(writeExternalStorage);
        if (hasReadExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            permissions.add(readExternalStorage);

        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            params = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
        }
        if (params != null && params.length > 0) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    params,
                    100);
        } else
            uploadVideo();
    }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    uploadVideo();
                }
            }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per Ali'S answer,I need to separately check for both permission whether they are granted or not.
**But** as per [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en),If any permission in a Permission Group is granted, Another permission in the same group will be automatically granted as well.And read and write external storage permission belongs to same group.

Comment: why not requesting both permissions seperately with different request code

Comment: your code calls `uploadVideo()` twice . once when you grant write permission and then after granting read permission. Maybe this was causing a problem.

Comment: Since this is crashlytics, I'm guessing you can't reproduce the issue locally. In that case, it would be best if you could post the code for `uploadVideo()`, and any other code that may call it, due to the possibility that `uploadVideo()` is getting called in a non-obvious way (one that skips the permissions check). Also want to see how you're handling this `AsyncTask`.

Comment: post your uploadVideo method code please.

Answer (score 0):

If you missed `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider"/>` in your AndroidManifest.xml,please add it and try again.